# jQuery Mobile Select doesnt show up

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying out jQuery mobile and I cant get the select input to work. As far as I can see it's set up like in the documentation.

Its in a fieldcontainer, and a label with the for property matching the select inputs id. And the jqm css file is listed in the head tag of the page.

Why is the select not showing up and how to I get it too?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Mod Chat</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/modpanel.css?=v1.0" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/toastr.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>      
    <!-- Start of chat box page -->
    <div data-type="page" id="chatBoxMain">

        <div id="fileBox">          
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Auto Grab Session:</label> 
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
            </form>
            <button value="Give me my session" onclick="getSessionFromFile()">Get Session</button>
                <button id="chatLoad">Load Chat</button>
            </div><!-- End of file box -->

        <div id="chatBody"></div>

        <div id="warningPanelBox">

            <label>Offender:</label>
            <div id="warnee"></div>

            <div  data-role="fieldcontain">

                <label for="selectPunish-1" class="select">Punishment</label>
                <select name="selectPunish-1" id="selectPunish-1">
                    <option  value="warn">Warn</option>
                    <option value="mute">Mute</option>
                </select>

                <select>
                    <option>24</option>
                    <option>72</option>
                    <option>999</option>
                    <option>99999</option>
                </select>

                <select>
                    <option>Avoiding Filter</option>
                    <option>Inappropriate Words</option>
                    <option>Sexual references</option>
                    <option>Drugs/Alcohol references</option>
                    <option>Trolling</option>
                    <option>Spamming</option>
                    <option>Coordinates leakage</option>
                    <option>External link</option>
                    <option>Inappropriate commander name</option>
                    <option>Bad alliance name</option>
                    <option>Bad bio</option>
                    <option>Bad planet name</option>
                    <option>Inciting Rule Breakage</option>
                </select>
            </div><!-- End of fieldcontain -->      
            <button id="punish">Punish</button>
        </div> <!-- End of warningpanel box -->

    </div><!-- End of chat box page -->     

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="js/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common.js"></script>
    <script src="js/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dateFormat.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.modpanel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blacklist.js"></script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2sy2wno/) . I think you have an issue with calling the jq scripts. see [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The jquery files are all there, and I believe in the proper order.

Comment: You need to reference both jQuery and jQM scripts in your `head` tag: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the jQuery UI link was conflicting with the jQuery Mobile. Removed the UI link and its smooth sailing.

Thanks for the help.